# Pull-up bar above double door's wall, safety

Tags: doors, mounting, joists, load-bearing, door-frame

## Question

Is it safe to use a wall mounted pull-up bar above a **double wide door**? The image below shows the door in question.

## Notes

Above the door, there are 3 cripple studs above the door, as indicated by the copper pennies laying atop the door casing. They are spaced 16 inches apart. The walls are plaster.

The pull-up bar would be attached by drilling and securing to the cripple studs.

If it is relevant, this would be for a home built in the 1920s, USA, midwest.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a suitably sized lintel resting on studs it is safe.  If the lintel was regarded as not weight bearing and built just strong enough to support the top of the door frame but no more then it might not be safe.

Either way I would worry with a doorway this wide that enthusiastic pull-ups might cause slight horizontal movement, in the direction in and out of the doorway (towards the camera), resulting in cracking of the drywall.

Comment: I should definitely see myself prone to a bit of a swinging motion, causing horizontal movement. Thank you!